# VB Web - DropDownList cannot retain selected data

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a new Web application that gets data from an SQL column via drop down menu to be used in an SQL query to show the data in GridView.

So far the data display is going fine, for now. But I keep having trouble with the drop down menu retaining the data I choose.

Every time I click my execute query code after selecting a random selection, it just automatically defaults into the 1st choice on the list.

Here is the code for reference, maybe someone has an idea what's wrong.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Div_Adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Call Inv_no()

End Sub

Public Sub Inv_no() 'Load Inv No data from SQL & place it in dropdown list

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT distinct [Inv No] from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZDIE_MAIN_HISTORY] order by [Inv No]", SQLCONN)
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    '-------------------
    Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Inv.DataSource = ddlValues
    Inv.DataValueField = "Inv No"
    Inv.DataTextField = "Inv No"
    Inv.DataBind()

    cmd.Connection.Close()

End Sub

Protected Sub exe_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles exe.Click

    Dim check1
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dsGROUP As New DataSet()

    check1 = Inv.SelectedItem.ToString

    Dim strSelectCmd As String = "SELECT [Project No],[Inv No],[Description] ,[Entry Date], convert(varchar(10),[Date],121) " _
                                 & "as [Date], REPLACE(RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Time], 131), 14)), 14), ':000', ' ') " _
                                 & "AS [Time],[Problem + Repair Details] ,[Status],[Remarks],[Location],[Measurement (OK/NG)]," _
                                 & "[Accumulative Stroke],[Preventive Stroke],[PIC],[Flag] FROM [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZDIE_MAIN_HISTORY] where " _
                                 & "[Inv No] = '" & check1 & "' order by [Project No]"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, SQLCONN)

    cmd.Connection = SQLCONN

    SQLCONN.Open()
    da.Fill(dsGROUP, "Die_Records")

    Dim dvGroup As DataView = dsGROUP.Tables("Die_Records").DefaultView

    WebDieView.DataSource = dvGroup
    WebDieView.DataBind()

    SQLCONN.Close()

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your pageload event.  Everytime the page loads you are running this

```
Call Inv_no()
```

So when your click event fires, it's also loading the page and resetting the dropdown

Try this in your pageload

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Call Inv_no()
End if
```

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source= ***;Initial Catalog=**;Integrated Security=SSPI;")//your connection string,or you can fetch from web config
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct [Inv No] from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZDIE_MAIN_HISTORY] order by [Inv No]" //check once query retriving values or not

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

        sqlConnection1.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            ddl_Country.DataSource = reader
            ddl_Country.DataTextField = "Inv No"
            ddl_Country.DataValueField = "Inv No"

            ddl_Country.DataBind()

        End If    
       sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: I hope it would work's, put this in Inv_no() method,